# Can I use map reduce for building a prefix tree (trie)?

Tags: mapreduce, streaming, batch-processing

I am trying to design an autocomplete feature (something similar to autocomplete for search engines like Google search).

My question is can I take a lot of logs which record the search terms searched on a given day and form a prefix tree from them using the map reduce paradigm?

I understand that each search term could be shuffled to the same reducer in that way we can get the same search terms on the same machine and easily calculate the frequency of each search term. But after that could I build a prefix tree within a reducer?

My goal is to form a prefix tree so that I can query that tree for all search terms starting with certain letters and then get the top 5 most frequent search terms from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that as long as you know the number of unique prefixes. You need to set the number of reducers to be the same as the number of unique indexes.

You can then construct a trie starting with prefix for this particular (Prefix/key) within the reducer and while you are building a trie you should set the output of reducer to be blank. Once you've built a trie you need to serialise and save it to disk.

In other words: you need to build an in memory data structure within each reducer and then save that data structure to disk, bypassing map reduce framework. You will need to implement serialisation yourself.
If worker runs out of memory on some keys, you can further split these prefixes by running another MR job.